# How do you JOIN with an if statement (conditional)

Tags: php, mysql, join, select, left-join

I want to do a JOIN in MySQL only if a value is not null. For example:

```
$db = "SELECT users.name, users.email, cars.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.id = users.car_id
WHERE users.id = :id"
```

But that statement does not work because if `users.car_id` is null, it won't return anything.

Instead I still want the results to come out and obviously `cars.name` will be `null`. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: What if you remove `WHERE users.id = :id` from the query? I think you should get it

Comment: @tcadidot0 I need that because I need to select that user's name, email, and if they have a car, to select their car name

Comment: How about you show an illustration on how your expected result would look like?

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making you original query into a sub-query then `LEFT JOIN` it again with the users table. This should show every name in users table even if the original query return `NULL`:

```
SELECT u.name,v.* FROM users u 
     LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT users.name AS UserName, users.email, cars.name
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.id = users.car_id
        WHERE users.id = :id ) v 
ON u.name=v.UserName;
```

Comment: Nevermind, i found my solution. So `LEFT JOIN` will still return the values, even if its null